# Debugging API in browser and Android app in emulator same time on one Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, debugging, xamarin, browser

I have Xamarin project based on ASP.NET Web API which is my 2nd sub-project in the same solution. I couldnt find similar problem anywhere so I think that sadly I have to run two Visual Studios which would like to to avoid.

What I want to accomplish is to debug API and android app in same time in one Visual Studio window. Is it even possible?

Example of manual test:
1. Android button click sends request to api.
2. API business logic has break point to check it.
3. Android app gets data from the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple startup projects in Visual Studio. Here's how to do it in Visual Studio 2015 (from MSDN):

1. In the Solution Explorer, select the solution (the very top node). Right-click the node to get the context menu.
2. Select Properties. The Solution Property Pages dialog box opens.
3. Expand the Common Properties node, and click Startup Project.
4. Click Multiple Startup Projects and set the appropriate actions. For more information, see NIB How to: Modify Project Properties and Configuration Settings.

You can also start debugging the Android app normally and launch the Web API project later on by right clicking it on the Solution Explorer and clicking Debug > Start New Instance.

Comment: what if I have two different projects ? one for the app and other for the web api ?